# How do I enumerate the keys and values of a Hashtable?

Tags: java, hashtable

I have a problem ; I have some data and I show it with `Hashtable` 
for example I write :

```
 Enumeration keys;
    keys=CellTraffic_v.elements();
    while(keys.hasMoreElements())
      outputBuffer.append(keys.nextElement()+"\n\n");
```

but it show me just values how can i show values and keys together?
for example this

if my key be "A"
and my value be "B" show me this :

```
A  B
```

Thanks ...

Comment: A better title might be: How do I enumerate the keys and values of a Hashtable

Comment: @Lachlan: Yes indeed. @OP: Took the liberty of changing it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have the key right? Use the key to get the value out of the map, and you have all the mappings. For example in Java with String as type for key:

```
for (String key : map.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(key + ":" + map.get(key));
}
```

.

Comment: this is costly. Crowder's solution is far better.

Comment: @akappa: Exactly in what way is this approach more costly? Both solutions iterates the collection of key-value pairs.

Comment: In your solution you make a lookup on each iteration, while in the entrySet solution you doesn't make a lookup at all.

Comment: And you know for a fact that the implementation of the entrySet()-method doesn't do a lookup for each key-value pair? As far as I can see both approaches have O(n) complexity.

Comment: If map is a HashMap, it is likely that both solutions are O(n), but if map is a TreeMap, this solution is O(n log(n)), while the entry set version is likely to still be just O(n).

Answer (score 18):

`Hashtable` implements `Map`. The [`Map.entrySet`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet()) function returns a collection (`Set`) of `Map.Entry` instances, which have `getKey` and `getValue` methods.

So:

```
Iterator<Map.Entry>  it;
Map.Entry            entry;

it = yourTable.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    entry = it.next();
    System.out.println(
        entry.getKey().toString() + " " +
        entry.getValue().toString());
}
```

If you know the types of the entries in the Hashtable, you can use templates to eliminate the `toString` calls above. For instance, `entry` could be declared `Map.Entry<String,String>` if your Hashtable is declared `Hashtable<String,String>`.

If you can combine templates with generics, it's downright short:

```
for (Map.Entry<String,String> entry : yourTable.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue());
}
```

That assumes `yourTable` is a `Hashtable<String,String>`. Just goes to show how far Java has come in the last few years, largely without losing its essential Java-ness.

Slightly OT: If you don't need the synchronization, use `HashMap` instead of `Hashtable`. If you do, use a [`ConcurrentHashMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) (thanks, akappa!).

Comment: And even if you need synchronization, use a ConcurrentHashMap.

Comment: @akappa: OOOoooh, nice. @OP: Reference: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html

Answer (score 1):

entrySet() returns an enumeration of the values in the Hashtable.
keySet() returns an enumeration of the keys in the Hashtable.
entrySet() returns the entries (key and value) as a Set

```
for( Iterator iter=hash.keySet().iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
    String key = (String) iter.next();
    String value = (String) hash.get( key );
}


for( Iteration iter=hash.entrySet().iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
    Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) iter.next();
    String key = (String) entry.getKey();
    String value = (String) entry.getValue();
}
```

or using generics, in which case your hash is a HashMap<String,String>

```
for( String key : hash.keySet() ) {
    String value = hash.get( key );
}

for( Map.Entry entry : hash.entrySet() ) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    String value = entry.getValue();
}
```